# Ability of Jenkins to checkin in SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, git-svn, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins, so please do forgive me if the question is stupid.

I have a project in GIT. and I have configured it in Jenkins. 
The same project also exists in a svn repo.

Now, whenever there is a checkin to the GIT repo, I would like Jenkins to make the same commit to the svn repository.

Jenkin should checkin the code to SVN as soon as it detects the checkin in Git.

How can we do this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is quite a unique problem and I am not sure why'd you want to keep the code in 2 version control systems. But to point you in the right direction, I am not aware of any available plugins yet but what I'd do is to create a post build script that gets the delta from GIT and then puts it in your local SVN copy of the project then commit it.

Comment: Jenkins is probably not the right tool for your needs. Check out http://www.codeography.com/2010/03/17/howto-mirror-git-to-subversion.html. Maybe this helps.